# Unwind segue removes original VC from view, why?

Tags: ios, swift

I am now staring to pull my hair over this one, so some help would be much appreciated.

I have a segue (slide from right) which works perfectly fine and slides a new `view` from the right into view.

I am now trying to go back and **unwind** the segue with the following custom class.

Everything seems to be working ok and I can see the first view sliding back from the left, but **the problem is that it immediately disappears from view.**

The only **`dismiss`** call I have is on the `originalVC` which in the unwind class below is the view that I am segueing back from which I want to dismiss.

```
//Segue: Unwind From Right
class UnwindSegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform(){


        let originalVC = self.source
        let destinationVC = self.destination

        originalVC.view.superview?.insertSubview(destinationVC.view, aboveSubview: originalVC.view)


        destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -originalVC.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
                        destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        },
                       completion: { finished in
                        originalVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}//end class
```

**EDIT**: Adding the view to `keyWindow` as per edit below has introduced a new set of issues, the `tabBar` disappears from view when I unwind.

```
class UnwindSegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform(){


        let originalVC = self.source
        let destinationVC = self.destination

        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(destinationVC.view, aboveSubview: originalVC.view)


        destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -originalVC.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
                        destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        },
                       completion: { finished in
                        originalVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}//end class
```

Here is the `SegueFromRight` class which is the initial segue

```
//Segue: From Right
class SegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform(){

        let originalVC = self.source
        let destinationVC = self.destination




        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(destinationVC.view, aboveSubview: originalVC.view)


        destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: originalVC.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
                        destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        },
                       completion: { finished in
                        originalVC.present(destinationVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}//end class
```

Answer (score 0):

You added the `destinationVC.view` to the `originalVC`, so when you dismiss your `originalVC` you're also getting rid of the `destinationVC.view`.
In other words:

Before calling dismiss on the `originalVC` you have to call:

`destinationVC.view.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I added the line you suggested right before the dismiss call but I am getting the same result :(

Comment: Also, usually when you're doing custom segues (or unwind segues) you insert your subviews on the key Window:
 `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(destinationVC.view, aboveSubview: originalVC.view)`
instead of doing it on `originalVC.view.superview?`

Comment: this segues/unwinds correctly but the `tabbar` at the bottom of screen disappears. When I segue foward and try to segue back (unwind) it doesnt work.